# How can I 'nuke Ubuntu from orbit'?

Tags: filesystem, permanent-delete

In short, I need to nuke it from orbit (Which seems to be the preferred method)

But how? Is there a package I can use, or do I just `rm -rf /` like a noob?

*I'll point out now that `rm -rf /` does very Little damage do a chunk of Linux, so probably is more of a Missile strike than nuke.*

**THIS QUESTION WILL BE WIKI'D WHEN I GET TO IT. So, post all the crazy and fun methods you have.**

Comment: There's plenty of existing questions that ask exactly that, and `rm -rf / --no-preserve-root` is already sufficient enough.  I don't find this question useful in any way, since it asks exactly the same as the existing duplicates, and the answers  are going to be mostly the same.

Comment: @DanBrown would you mind if I requested mods to merge your question and the linked duplicate to make community wiki out of it ?